# Determining object class in ndb PolyModel Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, data-modeling

It looks like the `ndb.polymodel.PolyModel` class used to have a `class_name()` method but as far as I can tell it has been deprecated.

I have a data structure using polymodel that is in the form of a parent User class with two child classes - Employee and Manager, and I want to do some basic checks throughout to determine if the User object is of the class Employee or class Manager.

At the moment, I am just calling the object's `.__class__.__name__` attribute directly, but I am wondering why the `PolyModel.class_name()` method was deprecated. Is there a better way to determine class inheritance?

Comment: Is `isinstance(user, Employee)` / `isinstance(user, Manager)` what you're looking for? ( https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance )

Comment: Ah, yes this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per comments above it looks like what you need is `isinstance(user, Employee)` / `isinstance(user, Manager)`.